# Django somehow cannot determine simple annotate function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to create an annotation on a queryset class that simply adds a boolean that is the result of some standard queries.

```
CustomQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    """ An extension of the traditional queryset to support
        filtering on accepting_offers """

    def annotate_with_accepting_offers(self):
        """ Add a lovely little variable to the SELECT that
            says if the listing is accepting offers.

            A <thing> is accepting offers when its:
                + not cancelled
                + expire date is today or in the future
                + has spaces left
        """
        return self.annotate(accepting_offers=Q(cancelled=False) & Q(expire_date__gte=date.today()) & Q(spaces_left__gt=0))

    def accepting_offers(self):
        """ Annotate with 'accepting_offers' and filter the results that are True """
        return self.annotate_with_accepting_offers().filter(accepting_offers=True)

    def not_accepting_offers(self):
        """ Annotate with 'accepting_offers' and filter the results that are False """
        return self.annotate_with_accepting_offers().filter(accepting_offers=False)
```

This unfortunately does not work, any ideas what annotation would?

If this was SQL, the top line would look like:

```
SELECT *, (cancelled=False AND expire_date >= ? AND spaces_left > 0) AS accepting_offers
```

---

**Edit**: 
The reasons I intend on making this annotation is to make filtering on the variable easier, which you can see in the next two proceeding functions.

These two methods would be used within a larger chain of queries, so (ironically) keeping it simple with an annotation should help.

Comment: Seeing the `&` bitwise operator raises some eyebrows, `and` is a logical operator in Python

Comment: Its the way recommended in the docs to _add_ these objects, [check it out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects). But you may be onto something

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen by using Q objects inside an annotate clause; that isn't what they are for. What results are you hoping to get?

Comment: I've appended the reason why I want this to the Q. But my intention is to end up having a filter-able field on each of my <Thing>s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this isn't what Q expressions are for at all. I think what you want is a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
return self.annotate(
  accepting_offers=Case(
    When(cancelled=False, expire_date__gte=date.today(), spaces_left__gt=0, then=Value(True)),
    default_value=Value(False),
    output_field=models.BooleanField()
  )
)
```

Comment: That's brilliant, I'll give it a shot now

Comment: Ah no, I get the following error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`. Any ideas?

Comment: Aha! Figured it out, we need to say the type it will output to. (Updating answer)

Comment: would you please update your answer to include the Case argument: `output_field=models.BooleanField()` and then I will accept your answer. (My edit was rejected)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'd be knackered in a months time when I have the same problem without it.