# Django: how to annotate a comparison as an expression?

Tags: django

I have a model including these two fields in my **models.py**:

```
class Dummy(models.Model):

    timestamp1 = models.DateTimeField()
    timestamp2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to list all values including the fact, if timestamp1 is greater than timestamp2. Instead of figuring that out in the template, I thought the right way would be to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) this in the **views.py**. Unfortunately this does not work:

```
from .models import Dummy

dummy = Dummy.objects.annotate(is_newer=timestamp1 > timestamp2)
```

I get the error:

> QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): False.

OK, annotate needs an expression, so I tried using [When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when):

```
from .models import Dummy
from django.db.models import When

dummy = Dummy.objects.annotate(is_newer=When(timestamp1__gt=timestamp2, then=True)
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
name 'timestamp2' is not defined
```

Now I am out of ideas. What should I do?

Comment: you have to use F() expression instead of timestamp2 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mainly had to improve these tings:

1. using [F() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)
2. using [Case()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)
3. using [Value() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions)

This finally worked for me:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, F, Value, When
from .models import Dummy

dummy = Dummy.objects.annotate(
    is_newer=Case(
        When(timestamp1__gt=F('timestamp2'),
             then=Value(True)
             ),
        default_value=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

I got inspired by iklinac's comment above and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48488955/13520223). Thank you!